# Filter elements from array in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table with the following structure:

```sql
select ["apple", "of", "the", "tree"] as array_col, 1 as label
union all (select ["boy", "of", "the", "streets"] as array_col, 2 as label);
```

I would like, via a query, to obtain a table without certain elements in the arrays. For instance, I want to filter the elements of the `array_col` array that are either `of` or `the`, obtaining the following table:

```sql
select ["apple", "tree"] as array_col, 1 as label
union all (select ["boy", "streets"] as array_col, 2 as label);
```

Is there an easy way to do this in biquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it with `REGEXP`. It may help to filter multiple array columns or huge tables

```
WITH arrays as (
    SELECT ["apple", "of", "the", "tree"] array_col, 1  label
    UNION ALL (SELECT ["boy", "of", "the", "streets"] array_col, 2 label)
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(array_col), r'"(of|the)",?',''), '$') array_col, label  
FROM arrays
```

Comment: the reason I updated the answer is because original version was not handling case if word that to be excluded is the last element in the array. while fixing this  - i also optimized the regexp a little :o) otherwise good answer :o)

Comment: oh. That's true! You are right, thanks))

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```sql
with arrays as (
    select ["apple", "of", "the", "tree"] as array_col, 1 as label
    union all (select ["boy", "of", "the", "streets"] as array_col, 2 as label)
)
select
  array(
      select x
      from unnest(array_col) AS x
      where x not in ('of', 'the')
  ) as array_filter,
  label
from arrays;
```